# Can the Mac OSX Lion dock automatically unhide when an application icon notification bounces?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, dock

I'm surprised not to find any related questions here. I'm a first time Mac OSX Lion user at a new job, and I'm wondering if there is an internal or third-party method of causing a hidden dock to unhide temporarily when an application icon bounces with a notification.

I can see the top edge of the Thunderbird icon jump up just barely onto the screen, for example, but it is easy to miss. Even at its smallest size, I would prefer to keep it off screen since I rarely use it.

Comment: It my experience, the icon bounces as high as the icons would be shown when the Dock isn't hidden. Do you have a very small Dock?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, it is at or near the minimum size and the icon just barely gets on screen.

Comment: Just resizing the Dock you have hidden isn't an option?

Comment: @DanielBeck Only if there is no alternative.

Comment: There is no such option, and third-party software or other hacks probably aren't worth the risk of breaking something...